# App Default ViewController name is not changing in xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift5

I have made new project then deleted the ViewController from `Main.StoryBoard` then added a new TableViewController view to storyboard make it initial viewcontroller and then in `viewcontroller.swift` file make it subclass to UITableViewController. And change view controller to ToDoListViewController.

Now the problem is if I am trying to change the `ViewController.swift` filename to ToDoListviewController it gives me error

> "Could not rename “ViewController.swift” to
>   “ToDoListViewController.swift”."

I have tried changing it from Identity and Type also but same error.

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check you don't have a file of that name already in the project folder but not added to your project. Also you could have just right-clicked on the `ViewController` class name and used "refactor" to change its name - Xcode will change the class name, the file name and fix up any references.

Comment: Just delete `ViewController` and create new `UIViewController` and named it to `ToDoListViewController`

Comment: Hi thanks it worked "refactor" earlier i tried but it was giving me same error so what i did i close and then again open myproject it worked wonders thanks @Paulw11

Answer (score -1):

Restart your xcode (Force Quit). Maybe helped